# Firebase data type

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

When I store in the firebase, all the data is stored as strings even if I define them as date, time, number.

```
interface Event{
  title:string,
  date:Date,
  startTime:Time,
  endTime:Time,
}

 event= {} as Event

 this.firebase.collection("Users").doc(this.currUID).collection("Events").add(this.event)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Firebase can only store JSON primitive types -- string or number is all I've seen in my experience. So when you pass it other types, it'll by default convert those to strings. If you'd like to store time as a number, you'd have to convert the Time object to a UNIX timestamp and send that in instead. Otherwise, you're stuck with string representations.